# How to throw errors or exceptions from Action in Play?

Tags: java, playframework

I read the official document of PlayFramework about Error handling. And I learned it is good to use `HttpErrorHandler` class.   And they say such error handling classes can catch errors or exceptions from `Action`.  And I saw methods of `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` class.  However, how does the `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` class distinguish errors or exceptions thrown from `Action`?  Some method such as `onServerError` takes `int` argument as its parameter, so in this case how does `Action` throw errors or exceptions? Does other page show it?

Comment: Which Play! version are you talking about ?

Comment: Normally, the latest version.  This question comes with the present official document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, an exception thrown in a Controller will result of a 500 http error code. The `onServerError` method will catch and handle this exception.

On the other side, 400, 401, 403 or 404 http error codes are called "Client error" in Play environnement. These errors are catch and handle by the `onClientError` method.

Thus, if you want to have a dedicated and customized page for 404 http error page ("Page not found"), build the given view and call it inside the `onClientError` method (you have the `statusCode` parameter to distinct 404 from 400, 401 or other http status code).

If you want to have a custom error page, you have to call the dedicated view in `onServerError` method.

Comment: About server side errors, I can understand.  However, in terms of "Client error",  I am not still sure. For example, if an user has a access to a page which doesn't exist, normally we have to reply with the 404 status code.  At the same time, if the client has an access to a page which is not permitted, we have to reply the 403 status code.  Does Play distinguish these different situation automatically without any setting?

Comment: Note that there is a difference between you returning a 404 Result in an action (ie. there was a route that lead the user to this action) and the user accessing something for which there is no route. Only in the latter case, the error handler is used. As far as 403s are concerned, how would play know whether the user has access to a certain resource? This case depends on how you do authorization.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  But I mean if we have some client errors which we want to distinguish distinctly, how should we implement? In Play I learned we can handle errors by using the HttpErrorHandler class. However, in some cases, we might want to prepare different error handling to different errors.

Comment: Kazuya - did you find the solution? I am using Silhouette for authentication. But if the authentication fails, my HttpErrorHandler doesn’t get called